# How can I get the epoch time for a specific time of day in a specific timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I'm trying to get the epoch timestamp, for the current day, in a specific timezone.

eg I want to know the epoch timestamp for 6am today in Pacific Standard time

I'm pretty close, but not sure how to adjust for the timezone:

```
const getTimestampFor10amPST = () => {
  const today = new Date()
  const year = today.getFullYear()
  const month = today.getMonth()
  const day = today.getDate()
  const timestampFor10amPST = new Date(year, month, day, 10, 0, 0, 0);

  return timestampFor10amPST.getTime()
}
```

How can I get this timestamp for the expected timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/):

```js
const dt = luxon.DateTime.fromObject({hour: 10, zone: 'America/Los_Angeles'});

console.log('Time in time zone: ' + dt.toString());
console.log('Unix (epoch) timestamp in milliseconds: ' + dt.toMillis());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.25.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

This works because when you don't provide date components, Luxon uses the current date in the provided time zone as a basis.  Also, when you provide any time components, the remaining time components are set to zero.  Thus all you need to set are the hour and time zone.

Comment: Keep in mind also that *your* current date might not be the same current date in the given time zone.  Luxon accounts for that correctly.

Comment: Also worth noting that 'America/Los_Angeles' will apply historic offset and DST rules for Los Angeles, it will not be specifically PST (presumably US Pacific Standard Time or Pitcairn Standard Time) which is always -8 and for that, a library really isn't needed. ;-)

Comment: Indeed, I was assuming that by Pacific Standard Time, the OP actually meant Pacific Time, inclusive of PST (-8) or PDT (-7) depending on which was in effect at the given time.  If actually you want a fixed -8 offset, then you could do this without Luxon.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
function calcTime(city, offset) {

    d = new Date();

    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();

}

// get Bombay time
console.log(calcTime('Bombay', '+5.5'));

// get Singapore time
console.log(calcTime('Singapore', '+8'));

// get London time
console.log(calcTime('London', '+1'));
```

another way to do it is using the options object as it has a timeZoneName parameter

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

// an application may want to use UTC and make that visible
var options = { timeZone: 'UTC', timeZoneName: 'short' };
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', options));
// → "3:00:00 AM GMT"

// sometimes even the US needs 24-hour time
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false }));
// → "19:00:00"

// show only hours and minutes, use options with the default locale - use an empty array
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }));
// → "20:01"
```

If you want it to return a date object instead of a string, the following solution will work for you:

```
var d = new Date();
var date_object = new Date(formatDate(d.toLocaleString('en-US', { 'timeZone': 'America/New_York', 'hour12': false })));
function formatDate(date){
    var date = date.split(', ')[0].split('/');
    var time = date.split(', ')[1].split(':');
    return date[2]+'-'+date[0]+'-'+date[1]+'T'+time[0]+':'+time[1]+':'+time[2];
}
```

Comment: Hi.  In your first approach, you are confusing a time zone for an offset.  For example, London isn't always +1, sometimes it's +0.  The second example doesn't address the question asked at all, as it returns a string.

Comment: Hi.  Sorry, but no.  That still doesn't work.  It's a common misconception that you can manipulate the `Date` object's time zone, but it can't be done reliably.  What you've done here is format a date string at a given time zone, but then by passing it to `new Date` you're interpreting that as if it were in the user's local time zone - not the time zone provided.   The `Date` object is not capable of being in a given time zone.  It is only a thin wrapper around a UTC-based Unix timestamp, with some functions that convert to/from local time.

Comment: Also, you're missing that in the original question, a Unix timestamp (aka "epoch timstamp") was asked for.   Your code does not give that.